# Pywinauto dont response

Tags: python, google-chrome, pywinauto

Im new in python and pywinauto, I need start a presentation in Chrome using pywinauto and Chrome_widgetWin_1, after I ran a program - Chrome started but just show a new tab, presentation didn't appear.
First part of program calls pdf a html presentations and add a path to Chrome,
second part is calling some Chrome widget for start a presentation but apparently it doesn't work.
I have no idea what can be the problem because I don't work with there up to now and on internet there is nothing helpful.
Can anyone has any experiences with that? I appreciate any kind of help, tnx :)

```
pdf = "\\CIT_presentation.pdf"         
htmlpres = "file:///...template_cit2.html#1"    
adobe = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Reader 11.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"    
chrome = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"    
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET    
from suds.client import Client
class Presentation:    
    def start(self):    
        from pywinauto import application    
        app = application.Application()    
        app.start_(chrome)    
        pwa_app = pywinauto.application.Application()    
        while True:    
            try:    
                w_handle =     pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(class_name='Chrome_WidgetWin_1')[0]    
                window = pwa_app.window_(handle=w_handle)    
                window.TypeKeys(htmlpres, with_spaces = True)    
                window.TypeKeys("~")    
                break    
            except:    
                pass
```

Comment: Is this the entire code?

I cannot see where you try to use the class, only where you define it..

Comment: I'm not able to understand what is it that you are trying to achieve. Can you add the steps that you are trying to automate in your question (I did not get the part about the widget)?

Comment: No it's just part of a code, because in this class there are a functions for Nao robot with which I'm working too and it's not important for this problem. After this definition I just call this --- Presentation().start()

Comment: Please provide detailed error description. Phrase "it doesn't work" is insufficient. What exception is thrown? What exactly happened? If it just hangs, please add `except Exception as exc:` line and `print exc` instead of `pass`. And provide the output.

Comment: Vasily ---- problem is that no error or exeptions is shown, it just open chrome and nothing happened ... I would like to help with more description but I don't know more info

Answer (score 2):

Probably you mixed 2 Application objects: `app` and `pwa_app`. `app` relates to started chrome.exe process, `pwa_app` is not connected to any process, it's just a "copy-paste" from SWAPY tool.

Just remove line `pwa_app = pywinauto.application.Application()` and replace all `pwa_app` objects with `app` ones.

[edit1] Just in case... You need 32-bit Python 2.7.

Comment: In this case when I remove pwa_app, it's same - presentation don't show and write me error <type 'exception.TypeError'>

Comment: It's another exception. At which line does it happen? Add `import traceback; traceback.print_exc()` at the exception handling code.

Comment: After debugging the problem can be in line "window = app.window_(handle=w_handle)", which is in TRY exception and after this line the program jump right to EXCEPT part, so line where presentation should be execute "window.TypeKeys(htmlpres, with_spaces = True)" doesn't run ...

Comment: P.s. after add traceback line it show same exception "<type 'exception.TypeError'> "

Comment: What is the full stack trace above or below TypeError message? Do you see it in stdout/stderr?

Comment: No I don't see anything else, just this error .... it repeatly write this error in new line, like this:     <type 'exception.TypeError'> '\n'  <type 'exception.TypeError'> '\n'  <type 'exception.TypeError'> '\n' ...

Comment: OK, try `sys.stdout.write(traceback.format_exc())` or `sys.stderr.write(traceback.format_exc())`. It should print script name and line number where exception occured.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to understand the question.. First let's make that code able to actually run, by :

```
import pywinauto
import time
import sys

htmlpres = "zcuba.dk/2014" 

chrome = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"

class Presentation:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def start(self):     
        app = pywinauto.application.Application()    
        app.start_(chrome)    
        pwa_app = pywinauto.application.Application()    
        while True:    
            try:    
                w_handle = pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(class_name='Chrome_WidgetWin_1')[0]
                window = pwa_app.window_(handle=w_handle)
                window.TypeKeys(htmlpres, with_spaces = True)      
                window.TypeKeys("~")   
                window.TypeKeys("{F11}") 
                break;
            except:
                e = sys.exc_info()[0]
                print e
                time.sleep(1)

p = Presentation()
p.start()
```

now it works here, I cannot find any errors... sorry

next debug version of the code, it looks less like your original version, and has a lot of output to help you pinpoint your problem!

```
import pywinauto
import time
import sys

htmlpres = "zcuba.dk/2014" 

chrome = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe'

class Presentation:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def start(self):
        print "starting the pywinauto application object, by default construction"
        pwa_app = pywinauto.application.Application()

        print "start chrome, via pywinauto, without parameters, for later interaction"
        pwa_app.start_(chrome)

        print "now I'll attempt to communicate with the chrome instance"
        while True:    
            try:
                print "find the first windows application, that has an open window, with the class name 'Chrome_WidgetWin_1' (typically a chrome tab/window instance)"
                w_handle =     pywinauto.findwindows.find_windows(class_name='Chrome_WidgetWin_1')[0]
                print "assigned a handle to the applications window:"
                print "handle is: " + str(w_handle)
                print "use the handle to create a window automation object"
                window = pwa_app.window_(handle=w_handle)
                print "window object created:"
                print window

                print "Now, attempt to simulate keyboard, and write the address in the chrome window (wherever focus is - we assume it is in the address bar - but some extensions can change this behaviour)"
                window.TypeKeys(htmlpres, with_spaces = True)      
                print "pressing enter to start the search for the address entered"
                window.TypeKeys("{ENTER}")
                print "pressing F11 to go for fullscreen - it is a presentation ;)"
                window.TypeKeys("{F11}")
                print "yay, we are done :)"
                break;
            except:
                print "Oh, no, an Exception, (something went wrong):"
                e = sys.exc_info()[0]

                print e
                time.sleep(1)

                print "will now retry_________________________________________"

print "build presentation object"
p = Presentation()    

print "start presentation"
p.start()
```

Comment: tested with python 2.7.8

Comment: I tried, It ran but  it's same as mine - chrome started, presentation didn't show but now program write me "<class 'pywinauto.application.AppNotConnected'>"

Comment: and I have python 2.7

Comment: That simply doesn't make any sense. This code does not attempt to show your presentation, but a test site on my website, and it works here. *notice*:_ if you are trying to use paths where "\" is followed by n, r, t, or any other character where the combination translates to a newline, tab, or other special char, the path needs to be litteral by placing a "r" in front like this_ r'c:\windows\...'

Comment: pywinauto.application.AppNotConnected: Application has not been connected to a process yet.  I assume it writes this over and over again?
it should come from the exception, if pwa_app has no connection to an application.

Answer (score 0):

Vasily --- yes, now it print a some errors

```
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>    
File "C:/.../Program.py", line 23, in start    
    window = app.window_(handle=w_handle)  
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 400, in window_   
    **kwargs)  
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 290, in _wait_for_function_success    
    return func(*args, ** kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py", line 60, in find_window
    windows = find_windows(**kwargs)    
TypeError: find_windows() got an unexpected keyword argument 'handle'
```

Comment: That's very strange. Function `find_windows()` has `handle` argument. See https://code.google.com/p/pywinauto/source/browse/pywinauto/findwindows.py Which version of pywinauto do you use? 0.4.2?

Comment: To make sure that `handle` is present go to `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\findwindows.py` and take a look at `find_windows`.